# SQL Select query for the mentioned condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are two tables **A** and **B**.

A has two columns **account_id** and **ad_id**. 
There are multiple **ad_id** for each **account_i**d.

Table B has multiple columns including  and ad_id.

I need to fetch all the **ad_id** for **account_id=100** then for all these **ad_id** I need to delete the data from **table B**

I need Help with the SQL query for the same.

Comment: what is your attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SELECT USING JOIN**

```
SELECT * FROM tableA A
INNER JOIN tableB B
ON A.ad_id = B.ad_id
AND A.account_id=100
```

**DELETE USING JOIN**

```
DELETE FROM tableB B
INNER JOIN tableA A
ON A.ad_id = B.ad_id
AND A.account_id=100
```

**DELETE USING NESTED QUERY**

```
DELETE FROM tableB 
WHERE aid_id IN (SELECT aid_id 
                 FROM tableA 
                 WHERE account_id=100)
```

Comment: Left join might be a bit dangerous here

Comment: thanks for suggestion

Comment: Thanks.. The nested query worked

Comment: if you got your answer please accept and upvote @pranjalmathur

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query

Delete from B where aid_id in (select aid_id from A where account_id=100)

This will delete the records for aid_id returned by sub-query.

Comment: Thanks.. It worked

Comment: Give it a upvote

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
delete b 
from tableB b
join tableA a  
  on a.ad_id = b.ad_id
 and a.account_id = 100
```